# Bash While Loop Continue Despite non 0 return

Tags: python, bash

Im writing a bash script that automates the usage of other python tests (imagedeploy, hydrationwiring). The bash script looks at a .txt list of device names, and then goes down the list and performs 2 things (imagedeploy,hydrationwiring) on each name in the .txt.

What happens is that hydrationwiring test will return a non zero return value at the end, which breaks the loop and ends the script.

I want the script to continue going down the list of p, regardless of non 0 returns, until each device in the list p has been touched.

My question: how can I make my while loop continue on regardless of non 0 returns.

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo "Usage: "devices.txt""
    exit 1
fi


FILENAME=$1
RESULTFILE="/home/user/ssim-results/RduLabTestResults"
date >> $RESULTFILE

while read p; do
    echo "TESTING $p:"
    LOGFILE="/home/user/ssim-results/RduLabTestLog_${p}.log"
    SUMMARYFILE="/home/user/ssim-results/RduLabTestLog_${p}.summary"




        #echo "STEP1: imagedeploy -d $p --latest-release4"
        echo "STEP1: imagedeploy -d $p --latest-release4"
        #imagedeploy -d $p --latest-release4

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]   #imagedeploy pass/failure condition
        then
            echo "STEP2: LLDP check"
            #runtests.sh -l INFO --vx-img -i /home/frogs/vmlocker/cloud/vx/latest-vx-rel $TESTS_HOME/tests/platform/HydrationWiring.py -d $p -T $LOGFILE -r $SUMMARYFILE
            runtests.sh -l INFO --vx-img -i $VXREL3 $TESTS_HOME/tests/platform/HydrationWiring.py -d $p -T $LOGFILE -r $SUMMARYFILE
            echo "STEP3: checking result"
            if grep --quiet success $SUMMARYFILE
                then 
                echo "$p PASS" >> $RESULTFILE
            else
                echo "$p FAIL" >> $RESULTFILE 
            fi

        else

            echo "imagedeploy failed"
        fi


done <$FILENAME
```

ImageDeploy is commented out because imagedeploy works as intended. The issue is in "step 2". The runtest.sh hydrationwiring

output:

```
FAILED (errors=1)
STEP3: checking result
```

It only tested the first device on my list because it failed, I would like the output to be something like this:

```
FAILED (errors=1)
STEP3: checking result

next device...
PASS
STEP3: checking result

next device...
FAILED (error=1)
STEP3: checking result

next device...
Passed
STEP3: checking result
```

etc

Comment: What python test? How is the script you showed related to your description? Please post an [MCVE], please let others reproduce the problem you are seeing. Include all the steps necessary to reproduce the problem. What is the problem exactly? What did you expect to happen? But what does happen on script execution? There is no question in your post.

Comment: With the code you're currently showing us, `$?` is the exit status of an `echo` command -- echo will only return non-zero if it can't write to the chosen file descriptor.

Comment: @KamilCuk Python tests that are local to the company Im new to programming and stack overflow. I updated the post some more

Comment: @glennjackman the intention was that if imagedeploy failed, there's no reason to continue with the other runtest test. So if if imagedeploy does give a non zero return, hopefully it will break out of the loop

Comment: `how can I make my while loop continue on regardless of non 0 returns` - the code should work as you want it to. There is no `break` nor `exit` - the loop should continue. Without providing us with a [MCVE], without providing steps to reproduce the problem, we can't help you. It's like "My car does not work. I can't show you my car, it belongs to the company. Why does it not work?". We don't know what is wrong with your code, until you show it. What does `runtest.sh` do? Why do you expect "success" to be in some file? Please check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net before posting here

Comment: Will do. Runtest.sh executes a very large python script that I don't have access to. It checks to see if servers are wired correctly using LLDP and net commands. The output of that runtest hydrationwiring test is success and I believe the output is being tracked in the summary log, so that's why is searching for success. My guess was that the loop was stopping after the last line of output: FAILED (error=1). I don't know how to ask the question properly I guess, but ill post back if I solve it. Thanks all

Comment: Maybe you want a command substitution? `output=$(the_script); if echo "$output" | grep -q FAILED; then echo IT FAILED`. Doesn't the python script also set nonzero exit status  upon failure?